# Split file into Array

Tags: java, arrays

Please help me with this problem I am trying to solve, I've been stuck on it for hours.

**Problem:** To read data from a text file. Structure of the data file:

- it will have multiple sets of data
- the data sets are separated by a blank line
- Each data set contains certain number of positive integers

**Task:** I want to write a Java program to read a user supplied data file and store each of the data set in separate array. I also want to display the size of each array as output followed by displaying the corresponding data set in sorted order (increasing order of numbers). I want to use `Arrays.sort(int[ ])` method to sort each array. I already got the reading of the file down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! I don't think I am writing the method to put them in the array and count the number of items right.

Below is the code for how I handle this file.

```
while(inFile.hasNext()){
       String line = inFile.nextLine();
       String[] lineArray = line.split("\\s+");
       list.add(line);
       Arrays.sort(lineArray);
       System.out.println("Total number of elements in array : " + lineArray.length );
       String a = Arrays.toString(lineArray);
       System.out.println(a.substring(1, a.length() - 1));
```

Comment: Hint: in `Arrays.sort(lineArray);` you're sorting strings, you probably want something else...

Comment: the line array should be converted to an integer array inorder to use Arrays.sort()

Answer (score 0):

You could start by reading the entire file into a `List` with [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-). Then you need to convert your `String[] lineArray` into an `int[]`. [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) to convert a `String` to an `int`. That might look something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    Path filePath = Paths.get(home, "file.txt");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] lineArray = line.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println("Total number of elements in array : "
                + lineArray.length);
        int[] arr = new int[lineArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        String a = Arrays.toString(arr);
        System.out.println(a.substring(1, a.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Java8*, you can use *stream* to simplify your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("./myinputFile.txt"))
            .map(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split("\\s+")).map(Integer::parseInt))
            .map(Stream::sorted)
            .forEach(t -> {
                t.forEach(v -> System.out.print(v + " "));
                System.out.println();
            });
}
```